# SPARQL-Gremlin: REST

Tags: sparql, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am currently using the following plugin for Gremlin: [GitHub](https://github.com/LITMUS-Benchmark-Suite/sparql-to-gremlin) -- It basically converts SPARQL to Gremlin. It works perfectly fine in the console but I am trying to execute commands via REST.

Is there a workaround when prepending a command with ":>" via REST?

### Gremlin Console:

```
gremlin> :> SELECT * WHERE { }
==> ...
==> ...
.
.
.
```

### Gremlin REST:

#### POST

```
{"gremlin": ":> SELECT * WHERE {}"}
```

#### RESPONSE

```
{"message": "startup failed:\nScript7.groovy: 1: unexpected token: : @ line 1, column 1.\n   :> SELECT * WHERE {}\n   ^\n\n1 error\n",
"Exception-Class": "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin Server doesn't know how to process raw SPARQL and I don't think that the plugin you referenced supports the server in any way. As a result, your attempts to send SPARQL to Gremlin Server are failing. The plugin would need to be modified in some way to make that work.